# Position of wires on 2010 f150 starter5.4 triton motor xlt

Tags: ford, starter, f-150, diagram

What is the position of wires on f150 2010 5.4?

Starter just spins, no crank.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

There are only two posts on the starter solenoid you need to worry about. The main wire from your battery goes to the thicker post which is away from the motor itself. The second is the energizer wire which turns the solenoid on and is driven by the ignition. It is the one which is off on the side. It should be pretty easy to tell which wires go where, mainly due to the size of the wire (battery=thick; ignition=thin), as well as by the size of the connectors. Don't mess with the connector on the solenoid which is wired to and nearest the starter.

Here's the backside of the solenoid/starter for reference to what I'm talking about (courtesy of RockAuto.com ... no affiliation):

[image]